# Use Object.freeze and object.unfreeze to reduce memory bloat in reactive pages with lots of table data rows

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm using an approach given [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vuex-data-flow/) to reduce memory bloat with my Vue.js app that has lots of table/row data. We are seeing memory bloat, especially in IE.
Ex. a page with a couple of rows can jump ~100MB when loading the page.

I've found that if I freeze each object that goes into the list/array where we store the row data the bloat drops significantly. 100MB -> 60MB

Is this the best solution to decrease memory bloat for a Vue.js app where we have lots of table data on multiple pages?
I've noticed that if no freezing occurs, IE can jump the memory to ~1GB after hitting 2-3 pages and doing 1-3 searches that result in 50 rows of data each! Adn everytime we do a search I'm trying to clear out the array so taht the garbage collector and clean up, but it really doesn't have much affect.

Additionally, when we have a column in a data table row that needs to be changed on the fly (ex. date or name) should I 
1. unfeeze the object 
2. make the change
3. freeze it again
4. push it back to the array

using something like [this package](https://github.com/gajus/object-unfreeze)

Comment: There is no such thing as `unfreeze`. You should call it by its real name: shallow copy.

Comment: so is that what https://github.com/gajus/object-unfreeze does?

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/gajus/object-unfreeze/blob/master/src/objectUnfreeze.js#L2). The example in the docs shows that it returns a new object, instead of "unfreezing" the passed one. (Btw, if you ask me, their shallow copy implementation is horrible).

Comment: well, do you know of a better one?

Comment: Just `array.slice()` and `Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(object)), object)` would suffice. They're simple enough that you usually don't need an extra function for them, let alone a library. If you don't care about a custom prototype, simplify the `Object.create(…)` to `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late, but you can also create an object in a mutable variable (`let`), and reassign the original object to the variable when you need to reset it.

For example:

```js
let obj = { objProp: "example" };

if (condition) {
    Object.freeze(obj);
}
else {
    obj = { objProp: "example" };
}
```